# How to Multiply Two Fields in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

i Have created a query and i want to calculate the order price from the Orders table by the inventory quantity in the Inventory table. How this can be in the design view?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your query with the desired fields and the fields you need for the calculation :

[image: make the query]

Save the query.

Then, right click in an empty field and select Build...
The expression builder will open. All you have to do is supply your expression :

[image: add the expression]

Keep practicing to expand your skills.

Comment: how to put currency sign infront of the result?

Comment: may i know how to put currency sign infront of the calculated field?